# Reclaiming the display interface of laptop mainboard using external display

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, motherboard

Instead of replacing a my macbook's broken display, I would like to utilize the Macbook mainboard's display interface with an external monitor.

In what ways is the Macbook's built-in display interface usable without using displays designed for this purpose?

This is a MacBook Pro (Late 2009) 15 inch.

*Example: Is it possible to pin out the mainboard interface to HDMI or DVI?*

**Important: The motivation for this question is that I currently believe that a broken built-in display on a Macbook reduces the number of maximum supported displays by one. I am aware that the external display ports can be used even if the screen is broken, and I am using all of them. I am still at a loss for the missing display in the mean time.**

Comment: You cant use the pin out method. It is for LCD display. Why are you not using the build in external display ports ?

Comment: Can you share the model of MacBook you have?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Late 2009) 15"